# What is the average length of time new sites are in Public Beta?

Tags: discussion, statistics, beta-phase

I know new sites are in Public Beta for at least 90 days to reach critical mass (says so [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace)).

Are there any statistics on how long public beta phases have lasted (for the sites that have gone through it already) before they either launched or got scrapped?

[The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) just passed 90 days, and is looking pretty good (except for question volume), so I was curious about statistics in this area.

Comment: Way over 90 days. Probably more like 360 days, counting only the more recent graduations. Maybe more like 500

Comment: Sites move out of beta? Since when?

Comment: [291 days](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NBOEm.png)? Give or take a few given any site which no longer exists isn't included in the calculation, and other various minor allowances.

Comment: Related (some stats in an answer, which quotes from a comment): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239464/162102

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 90 days limit is not a maximum limit, not anymore (it used to be, I think). Right now it's a minimum limit. In other words a Public Beta will last at least for 90 days and after that... it depends.

In alphabetical order (Days up to today in Public beta):

- [Chinese](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6388/chinese-language-usage): 210 days
- [French](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/29480/french-language-usage): 328 days
- [German](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18413/german-language-usage): 413 days
- [Linguistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics): 300 days
- [Movies  & TV](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies-tv): 223 days
- [Spanish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language-usage): 238 days

So, how does it work? As long as there is progress, the site will stay in Beta (and eventually graduate). As stated in the blog post [When a Site Grows Quiet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/):

> ### [How long can a site stay in beta?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/)
>
> The simple answer is, *it takes as long as it takes*. We’ll wait. If a site needs more activity, go out and [evangelize it](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/). As long as your site shows **steady progress** and continues to make the Internet a better place to get expert answers to your questions, it will march on.