# How long does it typically take for a beta site to launch?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, beta-phase, private-beta

[A proposal, "Open Source"](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82234/open-source), recently hit the necessary requirements to begin the beta stage.  But it does say it takes some time to launch the site.

How long does it typically take for a beta site to launch?

> This proposal has reached 100% commitment. We are preparing for its launch and expect to create it soon.

How long would "soon" be?

---

**EDIT:**

For clarification, I didn't know there was a "private beta" for only people how committed...

Here is a list so you know what I'm asking:

1. How long does it take for the private beta to launch
2. How long does it take for a site to go from private to public?

Comment: Private beta to public beta is quick, usually no more than 2-3 weeks. Public to graduation can take long years, we have lots of sites in public beta for over four years by now with no hint of graduation in the future, but also no risk of being closed

Comment: I don't think the private beta is restricted to people who committed anymore.  I think it is open if you have the link (which you can get to by following it from the A51 page)

Comment: Related: [What is the Stack Exchange (Staff) process of launching a site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199551/262755) | [Let's set better expectations for how long beta lasts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239464/262755)

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce the first seems like a dup to me?  The answers to both are there